# How to get good quality when converting digital video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I took my old NV-GS500 Panasonic camcorder; in order to finally turn all our recordings into digital media.

So far, things worked easily:

- On Ubuntu 16.04; I just had to connect the device and my laptop; via the DV/firewire cable
- Just using the standard settings (I didnt select any output format; just went for "single" unlimited file) ... *kino* created a capture.dv file for me
- That created a ~8 GB file for 40 minutes of video ... ok with me
- I then used a little script that reads does `ffmpeg -i infile -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 outfile` to turn that dv file into an mp4

But alas, the quality of the mp4 isn't that convincing. Especially on rapid movements, lots of pixelish stuff.

Thus, I want to improve the whole thing. And as now discovered that *kino* is actually "dead"; I am wondering what combination of tools gives me good quality; as easily as possible.

Update: the full command for ffmpeg is already given above, here is the output I am receiving when running that:

```
>  ffmpeg -i capture001.dv -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 test.mp4

ffmpeg version 2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[dv @ 0x2566420] Detected timecode is invalid
[dv @ 0x2566420] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, dv, from 'capture001.dv':
  Duration: 00:39:45.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28800 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: dvvideo, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 28800 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
    Stream #0:2: Audio: pcm_s16le, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1024 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] using SAR=64/45
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] 264 - core 148 r2643 5c65704 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libvo_aacenc) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 32000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libvo_aacenc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (dvvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (libvo_aacenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1449 fps=112 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10373kB time=00:00:57.93 bitrate=1466.7kbits/s    
video:9424kB audio:906kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.411332%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] frame I:29    Avg QP:22.01  size: 23022
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] frame P:826   Avg QP:24.37  size:  8655
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] frame B:594   Avg QP:25.43  size:  3086
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] consecutive B-frames: 29.4% 42.9% 14.7% 13.0%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] mb I  I16..4: 21.0% 76.6%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] mb P  I16..4:  1.7%  5.9%  0.5%  P16..4: 46.9%  9.4%  6.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:28.9%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 48.5%  2.5%  0.6%  direct: 3.3%  skip:44.8%  L0:46.0% L1:50.8% BI: 3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] 8x8 transform intra:73.6% inter:82.2%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 66.2% 56.2% 6.0% inter: 19.5% 23.4% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 14% 39% 12% 35%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 16% 33%  5%  5%  6%  6%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  9% 60% 14%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 20% 21%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:14.9% UV:1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] ref P L0: 62.5% 14.1% 15.9%  6.8%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] ref B L0: 81.5% 17.0%  1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x256dea0] kb/s:1331.94
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

(interrupted after a few seconds with ctrl-c)

Comment: Could you paste-bin the full FFmpeg command and also the complete terminal output? My suspicion is that your FFmpeg usage could be tightened up and a better result obtained...

Comment: @andrew.46 The ffmpeg command is already in the question; and I added sample console output for that.

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks ok although I suspect a modern FFmpeg can cope without the `-pix_fmt yuv420p`, this was selected automagically on my own system. Try deinterlacing, although I am not convinced this is the answer. Add the following: `-vf yadif=0:-1:0` (these are yadif defaults). If this makes an appreciable difference might be worth adding in  `mcdeint` as well. Otherwise, not for the first time, I am completely wrong :)

Comment: @andrew.46 Adding -vf yadif ... helps; but how do I make use of that `mcdint`?

Comment: Try something like: `-vf yadif=1:-1:0,mcdeint=2:1:10` This will be very slow unfortunately,

Comment: @andrew.46 Very slow, in deed. I put up a run to write 10 seconds ... and that took so long that I decided to ctrl-c that run. Given the fact that I have 8, 10 tapes to work on; each one with 30 to 60 minutes of content; nope, that is a nogo. Anyway; the yadif part alone seemed to help; so when yo are willing to put that into an answer, I will accept that (if you could add some explanation what that is doing). Btw. I tried to go with crf 0 earlier on; and was suprised that I still saw a lot of ugly artifacts in the output video ( before trying your suggestion).

Comment: > I suspect a modern FFmpeg can cope without the -pix_fmt yuv420p...

At least my environment, ffmpeg released on 2019-05-16 still seems to need `-pix_fmt yuv420p` option.  @andrew.46

Comment: For a similar issue I used HandBrake. Its default presets coped with the issue beautifully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is well worth running a deinterlacing video filter during your video encode and this may very well lessen some of the odd screen effects that you are seeing in your output video. A second thought, unrelated to motion artefact but well worth adding in, is the use of a de-noising filter.

**1. Deinterlacing:**

For FFmpeg the best and fastest choice is `yadif` which in the usual quirky geek fashion simply stands for 'Yet Another DeInterlacing Filter'!

`yadif` can be used with no options or you can specify an option for each of 3 fields:

1. **mode**: The basic interlacing mode to adopt
2. **parity**: The picture field parity assumed for the input interlaced video
3. **deint**: Specify which frames to deinterlace

The safe defaults can be specified on the FFmpeg command line as:

```
-vf yadif=0:-1:0
```

If you wish to alter these all of the deeper detail is contained here:

FFmpeg Filter Documentation: yadif 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif-1

A further deinterlacing filter called `mcdeint` (motion-compensation deinterlacing) can also be applied but you may find this *painfully* slow. A typical command line for use of this filter would be:

```
-vf yadif=1:-1:0,mcdeint=2:1:10
```

And again the fine detail of the `mcdeint` options can be seen in the FFmpeg documentation:

FFmpeg Filter Documentation: mcdeint 
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#mcdeint

**2. Denoising:**

A final though that may well be worth some experimentation is the use of a denoising filter, although this should not effect motion artefact it is still a well worth addition. Under FFmpeg there are a few choices but one well worth looking at is `nlmeans` (denoise frames using Non-Local Means algorithm). You will need [the very latest FFmpeg](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=c29b532a942233b5c804e620d475b3b888fe6e72) for this one.

To use this in the easiest command line try the following:

```
-vf yadif=0:-1:0,nlmeans
```

There is a hit with `nlmeans` in terms of encoding time, not as severe a penalty as is seen with `mcdeint` but still a consideration...

If you have an older copy of FFmpeg with no access to this newest filter there is an older denoise filter that can safely be used with trust in the sane defaults:

```
-vf yadif=0:-1:0,hqdn3d
```

I note on my own system that `hqdn3d` is very, very much faster than the newer `nlmeans`. Better? Well I suspect that is a debate for another forum :)

And hopefully a combination of any of these thoughts will solve your problem...

**References:**

- [Non-Local Means Filter for FFMPEG](http://www.dirk-farin.net/projects/nlmeans/index.html)
- [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)
- [What is Deinterlacing? Facts, solutions, examples.](http://www.100fps.com/)

Comment: Lots of stuff ... will digest your input tomorrow I hope.

Comment: No worries, I have had a lot of fun putting this answer together :).

Comment: There are also the [bwdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#bwdif), [nnedi](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#nnedi), and [w3fdif](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#w3fdif) deinterlacing filters. I haven't  compared them yet.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I was wondering when you would be drawn out :)

Comment: I almost answered but New Years induced laziness convinced me not to, but it was a good thing since your answer is more detailed and explanatory than what I had in mind. The *mode* is worth experimenting with in yadif: for my last batch of vids mode 1 looked much better for that particular content. I wish nlmeans was around when I was dealing with lots of VHS stuff.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I tried nlmeans and found it to be **much to slow** for  me; and I couldnt spot much differences to the (way faster) -vf yadif=0:-1:0,hqdn3d setting. So I will probably capture all my videos first; and then use your settings to turn them into mp4.

Comment: Can/should all of these be combined into one encode/run, or do they need to be run separately?

Answer (score 3):

You can quickly and easily achieve very good quality using **Handbrake** app. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install handbrake
```

I suggest you encode to x264, it's currently most commonly used coded and you can have quite small file while preserving good quality. For private archive I recommend setting up Constant RF (rate factor) to between 16 and 18 (lower = higher quality and larger size).

[image]

If your video is noisy (it's probably is), there's also very neat denoise filter:

[image]

You might also need to deinterlance your source. As for audio... 320 kbps MP3 or AAC should give great results for personal archive. Everything can be set in Handbrake's GUI.

Comment: handbrake is my best for compressing video, concerning the RF I put it in 24.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it a try ... but then turned back to using kino and running ffmpeg myself. Simple reason: kino did immediately recognize my camera; handbrake didn't; just asked me to select some device ... probably just an easy thing; but as said - the other worked out of the box. Still: great answer!